# Disable DTS audio enhancements permanently

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, equalizer

I have an HP Spectre x360 with DTS audio.  I'd like to permanently disable the "audio enhancements" in the DTS control panel. Even if I disable them by unchecking the box, the next time a plug my earphones in, they are automatically enabled again (and to make things more confusing, the enhancements checkbox stays unchecked -- I have to check it and then uncheck it to disable the enhancements again).  I'm looking for a fix for this if there is one.

Comment: please also describe the problem this causes to your listening, or whatever audio symptoms you are getting that bring you to the conclusion that it is not disabling.

Answer (score 1):

Myself and many other HP users have been experiencing the same problem. As an audio engineer, I can attest that the DTS "enhancements" are far from improving, in fact, they're downright atrocious. Whoever wrote and approved that DSP should be fired.. from a cannon.

Anyways, I have found a solution which I posted [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/DTS-Audio-Control-Panel-Audio-Enhancements-dont-stay-off/m-p/5480466#M73233) on the HP support forums.

In case they decide to take it down for being useful, something their own tech support fails to be, I have copied it below:

RIGHTO! Download the latest HP Spectre x360 audio drivers (sp74372.exe) and run that file. It's not the installer itself, but just unpacks the installer (and runs it). You will be asked where to unpack to. Choose a location you know and go there once the unpacking is done.

Now navigate to **(unpack folder)\Fre\ISST\** and delete these 19 files:

```
dts_intel_coinstaller_x64.dll
IntcADSP*.* (7 files)
intel_coinst.dll
MaxxAudio*.dll (6 files)
RtkMic??.dll (2 files)
WavesS*.exe (2 files)
```

You may not need to delete *all* of those, but I did and the issue is solved.

Now run the installer. In a very handy turn of events, the installer will uninstall the previous drivers for you, restart Windows, then install the new driver. Thankfully it doesn't complain that some of the files are missing and therein lies the solution. I have removed the DLL files that contain the horrible DSP code.

Time to verify.
The DTS control panel won't run from the installed shortcut anymore, but if you go to the ISST folder, you can run RtkNGUI64.exe, go to Listening Experience tab and toggle the Audio Enhancements checkbox - it will make no difference to the sound... **FINALLY!!!**

**< sarcasm> Once again, I congratulate the HP service team for acknowledging the problem and working so hard to fix it quickly for their paying customers. :|   < /sarcasm>**

Comment: Please include all steps that are necessary to solve the problem in your answer. Other sites might go down or be restructured, making your answer invalid.